# Is there a way to connect to an Open To Lan World without a connection to Mojang/Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

As the title implies I am trying to connect to an Open To Lan world in order to play with siblings. I had it setup and running and managed to connect my sibling's computer to the world and mess around there a bit. After disconnecting and trying to let my sibling join later today I get an error message that says the authentication servers are down for maintenance. After checking on my computer, Mojang servers seem to be up and running.

My guess is that since my sibling is younger there are restrictions to keep them from seeing things they shouldn't see on the internet.This also stops them from connecting to Mojang at all times. I tried looking for solutions on Arqade but couldn't find any that seemed similar to my problem.

From what I understand a connection to Mojang is only required upon joining a server and not while playing.

**Since a connection with Mojang is only necessary upon joining an Open To Lan world, would it be possible to bypass that and just directly connect to the world?**

Comment: A smaller question I have would be, why this connection is required in order to join the world? Why would Mojang need to authenticate the player joining an Open To Lan World?

Comment: that error is completely unrelated to age

Comment: @Topcode I might not have explained well. Since my sibling is younger we have firewall restrictions set to avoid any problems with seeing something they shouldn't be seeing on the internet.

Comment: I understand that Minecraft connects to Mojang servers as an anti-piracy measure to avoid having anyone joining the server illegaly. Since we both have a Minecraft account that shouldn't be a problem. While looking into the problem I found out that I need to turn off online mode by setting it to false. While looking through the world files I could not find a place to turn it off. Where can I turn off online mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time looking up certain how to find my way around having to connect to Mojang servers I reached a solution.

Instead of using the Open To Lan option I decided to use a server that runs off my computer. I downloaded the server files from the Minecraft website for servers [here.](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server/) And then after following the instructions on how to setup a Minecraft server from [Servermania](https://www.servermania.com/kb/articles/how-to-install-minecraft-server-on-windows-10/) managed to have it setup.

The only thing I had to do then was change offline mode to false in server properties (after receiving multiple warnings not to do this. Which makes sense but I was rather desperate) and reap my rewards. Just tell the other players who you want to join your ip adress and the port and let them join. Obviously skins won't work but that's fine for all I care.

Obviously you have to have a rather decent PC to manage the server but it worked out in the end.

Side note: To become operator in your server replace the two brackets in your ops.json file with

```
[
  {
    "uuid": "YOUR-UUID",
    "name": "YOUR-MC-USERNAME",
    "level": 4,
    "bypassesPlayerLimit": true //(or false here depending on what you want)
  }
]
```